# Do I need to use Apple In-App Purchase when digital goods are also made available outside of the app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have a website which is an exam question bank for a variety of topics. A user can purchase a topic and unlock questions for the specific topic.

I'm currently writing an app which provides the same functionality as the website. Users can create an account on either the website or app, and anything purchased through the website will appear on the app.

I understand that Apple state that you must use their In-App purchase kit for digital goods, however because the purchase unlocks the same content not just in the app, but on the website, am I able to redirect users who wish to purchase a topic via the app to the website, sidestepping Apple's In-App Purchase?

Comment: If they have previously purchased on your web site and then they log in to the app (or they purchase something on your web site and then open the app) you can provide access to that content in your app.  You can't redirect them in the app, open the web site in the app, or even instruct them to go to the web site in the app.  Any purchase made in the app must be via IAP.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is app store policy related and not programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules are very simple:

1. Any digital goods or services purchased on the device must go through an In-App Purchase.
2. Any physical goods or services must *not* go through an In-App Purchase (like eBay, Uber etc. )
3. Any digital goods or services purchased elsewhere do not go through an In-App Purchase.
4. You are not allowed to direct the users from your app to a website where they can purchase digital goods or services to use on their iOS device.

So selling things through your website is fine. Directing users from the app to your website will get your app not allowed on the store.

Comment: "Directing users from the app to your website" is up to the individual reviewer. I remember Evernote 3rd-party apps being rejected because they used the Evernote login dialog and that was interpreted as linking through to payment. You just need to mention a URL, not a clickable link, for a zealous reviewer to crawl on and decide if there's a payment mechanism somehow linked.

Answer (score 0):

> I able to redirect users who wish to purchase a topic via the app to the website, sidestepping Apple's In-App Purchase?

This reason would cause your app to be rejected by the App Store review team and you'd be asked to integrate In-App purchases within the app.

Also note that Apple receives takes a fixed 30% of commission from all the sales made via app and In-App purchases.

From the [App Store Review Guidelines - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase):

> **3.1.1 In-App Purchase:**
>
> - If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), ***you must use in-app purchase***. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

Regarding the Apple's commission:

- [App Store - Principles and Practises](https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/principles-practices/)

> Developers earn 70% of sales from in-app purchases and ***Apple collects a 30% commission***.

<sub>Pay attention to the highlighted.</sub>